# How does gdb print stl containers

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

How does GDB pretty print this container?

```
const unordered_map<string, int> map{{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}};
```

```
(gdb) p map
$1 = std::unordered_map with 2 elements = {["world"] = 2, ["hello"] = 1}
```

How can I get this functionality for my custom container?

Comment: Look up "gdb pretty printer"

Comment: Ok I see the pretty printers are located in the stl objfile `libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does GDB pretty print this container?

By using [pretty-printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html).

The pretty-printers for `libstdc++` `std::vector`, `std::unordred_map` etc. are [part of](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py;hb=HEAD) and shipped with `libstdc++`.

> I see the pretty printers are located in the stl objfile

No, they are not. A filename pointing to them is in the object file, but not the pretty-printers themselves.